# Php string exploding into a specific array

Tags: php

Following is the String that holds the contact info. This string is dynamic i.e. sometimes new fields eg: mobile number may add up or old fields say: tel number may delete.

```
                              <?php $str = 
                                "tel: (123) 123-4567
                                fax : (234) 127-1234
                                email : abc@a.a";
                                $newStr =  explode(':', $str);
                                echo '<pre>'; print_r($newStr); 
                              ?>
```

Output of the code is:

```
                        Array
                            (
                                [0] => tel
                                [1] =>  (123) 123-4567
                                                                fax 
                                [2] =>  (234) 127-1234
                                                                email 
                                [3] =>  abc@a.a
                            )
```

But the output needed is in the following format:

```
                        Array
                            (
                                [tel] => (123) 123-4567
                                [fax] =>  (234) 127-1234            
                                [email] =>  abc@a.a
                            )
```

I tried exploding it in may ways... but didn't work. please guide.

Comment: you are exploding with delimiter `:`. So between `(123) 123-4567` and `fax` there is no separator like `:`. So you are getting both of them in the same value.

Comment: @PankitKapadia What delimiter shd i use? I didn't find any other meaningful separator.

Comment: Is there a newline between each set of values in the text? If so, use "\n"

Comment: @user1871640 - delimiter you used is not a problem. You can use any. I just want to say that you are not getting separate values because there is no delimiter between `(123) 123-4567` and `fax`

Comment: @user1871640 - check the UPVOTED answer !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$txt = 
                            "tel: (123) 123-4567
                            fax : (234) 127-1234
                            email : abc@a.a";
$arr = array();
$lines = explode("\n",$txt);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $keys = explode(":",$line);
    $key = trim($keys[0]);
    $item = trim($keys[1]);
    $arr[$key] = $item;
}
print_r($arr);
```

[**CodePade**](http://codepad.org/LH72eUd3)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter way with [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*)/', $str, $matches);
$newStr = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($newStr);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [tel] => (123) 123-4567
    [fax] => (234) 127-1234
    [email] => abc@a.a
)
```

[example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G5LQEe)

This example assumes, however, that each data pair is on a separate line as in your provided string and that the "key" contains no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $newStr as $key=>$value){
      echo $key;
      echo $value;
}
```

Comment: OP does not wants to just echo(show) he wants to just echo ... check [tpaksu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13815039/1723893)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = 
    "tel: (123) 123-4567
    fax : (234) 127-1234
    email : abc@a.a";

$contacts = array();
$rows = explode("\n", $str);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    list($type, $val) = explode(':', $row);
    $contacts[trim($type)] = trim($val);
}
var_export($contacts);
```

returns

```
array (
  'tel' => '(123) 123-4567',
  'fax' => '(234) 127-1234',
  'email' => 'abc@a.a',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use preg_split with the delimeter ":" and "\n" (newline character):

```
$newStr = preg_split("\n|:", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str =
    "tel: (123) 123-4567
    fax : (234) 127-1234
    email : abc@a.a";

$array = array();
foreach (preg_split('~([\r]?[\n])~', $str) as $row)
{
    $rowItems = explode(':', $row);
    if (count($rowItems) === 2)
        $array[trim($rowItems[0])] = trim($rowItems[1]);
}
```

You have to use preg_split because there could be different line-ending on each system. There is also possibility that the string is invalid so you should handle that (condition in the foreach cycle)